# POST and GET between Python back-end and PHP front-end

Tags: php, python, web, python-requests

I am trying to make python back-end send a message to PHP front-end via POST and GET. I found the following snippet after some Google search. Trying to get it working to understand how both ends talk to each other.

I am using "[Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)" for HTTP POST.

Python code (test_bot.py):

```
import requests

userdata = {"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Doe", "password": "jdoe123"}
resp = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1/front.php', params=userdata)
```

PHP code (front.php):

```
<?php
$firstname = htmlspecialchars($_GET["firstname"]);
$lastname = htmlspecialchars($_GET["lastname"]);
$password = htmlspecialchars($_GET["password"]);
echo "firstname: $firstname lastname: $lastname password: $password";
?>
```

After run the python code, I went and check the php output here: http://127.0.0.1/front.php

All I get is:

> firstname: lastname: password:

How do I get the data? I have both files under `/var/www/html`

I am fairly new with this concept. I am sure I am missing something. Any pointer would help.

thanks.

Comment: (1), you use POST to transmit the data, but use `$_GET` to retrieve them (there's also a `$_POST` variable), (2) you don't store the data anywhere, so it will be gone on the next request.

Comment: Sorry don't follow. I get status code of 200 back, the data must be going somewhere. What I am trying to figure out how do I make the PHP front-end code pick up and display the transmitted data.

Comment: Use `$_POST` to access data from the POST body. `$_GET` is for retrieving data from the URL query string.